# Запуск проекта на встроенном IIS сервере windows

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

*Visual Studio* каждый раз при компиляции грузит свой *IIS Express*, что занимает около минуты и раздражает.

Я включил *IIS Server Windows*. Как мне теперь пробросить проект *студии* на него?

Comment: если ВЫ это затеяли только для "ускорения" процесса загрузки то напрасно, если идти тем путем которым Вы хотите пойти то перед каждым открытием сайта в браузере Вам будет необходимо делать публикацию приложения посмотрите [здесь](http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/sites/level3/3_2.php). Сайт то конечно все равно надо будет "развертывать" но если Вы тока отлаживаете, то наверно еще рано

Comment: Вроде ж в свойствах проектах была возможность выбирать Local IIS где требовалось создать виртуальную папку но для отладки это не очень хорошо так как если сайт требует авторизации то ее нужно каждый раз проходить.